# Celery and RabbitMQ I am not receiving updates for my task

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

How are you? I am working on django 2.2, celery 4.4.2 and
In my tasks.py file I have the following code

```py
@shared_task
def start_task(dict):
    objectLogic = LogicProcess()
    # print('dict', dict)
    task = objectLogic.RunProcess(parameters=dict)
    print("Estado de la tarea: {}\r".format(task))
    return task
```

it calls a function, at the end of it I update it but I don't receive a response.

```py
current_task.update_state(
                state = 'PROGRESS',
                meta = {
                    'current': oer_number,
                    'total': TotalOER,
                    'percent': int((oer_number * 100) / TotalOER)
                }
            )
```

ah yes ... at the end of the task I make it return

```py
return {'current': TotalOER, 'total': TotalOER, 'percent': 100}
```

well if i get one (the first update) i can't see the others

```
celery -A ost worker -l info -n worker
task 528454cb-724e-48bc-b95e-9d3a124b22e1
Task status     {}
task 528454cb-724e-48bc-b95e-9d3a124b22e1
Task status     {'state': 'PROGRESS', 'result': {'current': 2, 'total': 66, 'percent': 3}}
```

or

```
task_id=528454cb-724e-48bc-b95e-9d3a124b22e1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2
task_id=528454cb-724e-48bc-b95e-9d3a124b22e1 HTTP/1.1" 200 74
task_id=528454cb-724e-48bc-b95e-9d3a124b22e1 HTTP/1.1" 200 110
```

or just nothing but the one it calls if it works, it's just the state that doesn't return me

in both files **tasks.py** and **function.py** import

```py
from celery import shared_task, current_task
```

the celery.py file contains

```py
# from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ost.settings')

app = Celery('ost', backend='amqp')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
# should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

in django's view I call it like that

```py
from celery.result import AsyncResult

task = start_task.AsyncResult(task_id)
            data = {}
            if isinstance(task.result, dict):
                data['state'] = task.state
                data['result'] = task.result
```

I tried it with `if task.ready()` but it doesn't meet the condition, although as I already mentioned if it ends the function and returns

Anyway, I do not know what else to indicate, any idea will be tested and some things that I review [link 1](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html), [link 2](https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/django-celery-and-rabbitmq/), [link 2](https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/django-celery-and-rabbitmq/)

PS: I update the task status within a for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned the updates were within a FOR cycle, for it I made a `Recursive functions` where `AsyncResult` is found, in my case the django view. This retrieves the status of the task. And I end it (`task.state = SUCCESS`) when the oer_number = TotalOER.

Seeing what with perspective was logical, it is **updated** in a `FOR` cycle it is **recovered** in a `recursive functions` mmm things that one forgets. So it only recovers **a single value**